# Concurrent sessions per user in HIPPO CMS

Tags: hippocms

I am new to Hippo CMS. I am using Hippos CMS 7.9.3 community addition.I am using eclipse as an IDE. We are currently using the default Editor,Author and Admin User.My issue is when the same user name and password being used by two different systems one of them is automatically logged off. So how can I set concurrent user login for a particular user.

Answer (score 2):

In Hippo CMS 7.9 it is not possible to log in using the same userid from two different browsers or two different systems. If you do try it, the other session is logged out as you described. This is expected behavior and cannot be configured.

If you want to test using multiple editor users, it's real easy to add some more users via the management console, see [the user guide](http://www.onehippo.org/7_9/library/administration/user-management.html).

Cheers, Oscar